# flutter sqflite transaction does not insert record after successfull commit

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

Using sqflite database at Flutter project and I need some help.

Below you can see my transaction code

```
  await db!.transaction((txn) async {
    var batch = txn.batch();
    for (DespatchTransaction despatch in transactions) {
      if (isSynced) {
        despatch.isSynced = 1;
        despatch.syncDate = DateTime.now();
      }
      final List<Map<String, dynamic>> exist = await txn.query(tableName, where: "id =?", whereArgs: [despatch.id]);
      if (exist.length == 0)
        _insert(despatch, txn, batch);
      else
        _update(despatch, txn, batch);
    }
    await batch.commit(continueOnError: false).then((value) {
      if (value.length > 0) dbSaveResult = value.length;
    });
  });
```

And insert code block as below

```
  batch.insert(tableName, item.toMap(),conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
```

I have turned on the debug mode at sqflite database and can see the transaction insert statement and commit command

```
D/Sqflite (14181): [2,Sqflite(850)] INSERT OR REPLACE INTO DespatchTransactions (id, isActive, createdUser, createdDate, updatedDate, updatedUser, isSynced, syncDate, sourceId, sourceName, applicationType, statusId, companyId, branchId, warehouseId, employeeId, accountId, currencyType, tradeType, documentType, subDocumentType, directionType, documentDate, transactionDate, projectId, costCenterId, despatchAddressId, invoiceAddressId, isReturned, serial, number, documentId, description, lineCount, lineExtensionAmount, taxInclusiveAmount, taxExclusiveAmount, allowanceTotalAmount, chargeTotalAmount, payableRoundingAmount, payableAmount, vatTotal, taxTotal, deductionTotal, cargoTransactionId, detailId, eDocumentId, integrationId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) [da4d5b2a-3730-455f-9388-f1cdcc59c3c7, 1, c0e7b68a-90af-488d-97ce-08d83de6f8df, 2021-08-11T21:45:18.373228, 2021-08-11T21:45:18.373238, c0e7b68a-90af-488d-97ce-08d83de6f8df, 1, 2021-08-11T21:45:18.371369, 9995af04-c946-42c3-a6a7-fd6c9374ec21, Eqlem Mobil Uygulama, 9998, 5155eb76-8ff0-4068-59c5-08d83de65f2d, bd1b9d20-4ce2-4b23-0352-08d83de81a96, a4d26dcb-ab72-4c8b-9170-baefe4a0ea70, 645193c6-002e-4fe2-5ac5-08d83de82cd8, 88293574-97c7-452b-b629-0683c2bd8268, 1, 0, 102, 101, 1, 2021-08-11T12:17:51.204862, 2021-08-11T12:17:51.204869, acaf97d2-00d0-49b2-ff24-08d87f29ef6c, 6325c200-a695-4e45-6c75-08d87f294e0b, 6b8e77a0-6aa1-44bf-8b5b-0eca7b2b5bac, c62f3f2f-d1da-4cea-8de9-82e1e3359e46, 0, MBL, 0, E61C6CD99D7, 1, 900.0, 1062.0, 900.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1062.0, 162.0, 0.0, 0.0]
D/Sqflite (14181): [2,Sqflite(850)] inserted 23

D/Sqflite (14181): [2,Sqflite(850)] COMMIT
```

When I check the record on the table no record was inserted, and Flutter does not throw any exception at all.

I need some advice/help please?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing both batch calls (i.e. performed at the end) and direct calls in the transaction which won't likely provide the behavior you expect. You query by id but the inserts and updates are only perform at the end (so queries will never return the item inserted/updated in the transaction). Not sure I'm clear though. The list of result of the batch (you only print the number of statements executed not the insertion/update results) should give you the result for each insert and update (i.e. maybe the insert returns 0).

My first advice would be to try without batch first and await (and print for debugging) the result of each insert/update. Once you're fine with the result, you can try to optimize with batches (or not as it won't likely give you much benefit here, batches are just a group of statements sent to the native implementation).

Comment: thank you @alextk the problem was at update function. I have forgotten to add , `, where: "id=?", whereArgs: [item.id], ` to batch update call